# Why do my face sets have holes in them?

Tags: sculpting

I'm sculpting a character in Blender, and I'm attempting to hide parts of it using face sets. When I use the `Draw Face Sets` tool, the face set appears to have holes in it:

[image: The face set, appearing to have holes in it.]

For reference, the topology of the sculpt looks like this:

[image: The topology of the sculpt.]

And when I hide everything but the face set, it looks like this:

[image: Just the face set, with everything else hidden.]

I use Dyntopo to control the exact amount of detail throughout certain parts of the sculpt, but I can't seem to draw face sets at all unless I temporarily disable it.

Can anyone pinpoint the cause of this? Thanks in advance!

Update: It looks like I can make perfectly good face sets using `Box Face Set`, but still not with `Draw Face Sets`. Why is this?

[image: A face set made with box face set.]

Answer (score 2):

**(Please read the update at the end of this post btw)**

I found two solutions!

The first solution I discovered was setting `Propagation Steps` to anything higher than `1`.

[image: Setting Propagation Steps to 2.]

Checking `Topology` under `Auto-Masking` had the same effect!

[image: Checking the Topology checkbox.]

Now I can draw solid face sets.

[image: A solid face set.]

**Update:** I think i just found the true underlying issue here. I realized that I couldn't "extend" face sets by holding `ctrl`, nor could I smooth them out using `shift`. I created a new file and experimented with a subdivided default cube in attempt to trace back to the root of the problem.

First, uncheck everything under `Brush` > `Advanced` > `Auto-Masking`, like so:

[image: Auto-Masking settings with everything unchecked.]

No need to increase `Propagation Steps` unless you know what you're doing (I don't).

Next, under `Options` in the top right of the Viewport, ensure that everything under `Auto-Masking` is unchecked.

[image: Auto-Masking settings with everything unchecked.]

You're all set! Draw Face Sets should function normally, exactly as it would in a fresh .blend file.